# form onSubmit vs onClick

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs

```
<form>
  <input />
  <button
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("clicked");
    }}
  >
    click
  </button>
</form>
```

[image: Edit zrzz6pj7kx]

If I move the `onClick` handler to [`form`'s `onSubmit`](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlmrl6lqv5), I will get the exact same behavior.

Most answers I googled suggested that the difference is `onClick` will not react to submitting form via `return` key press but that's not true as seen in the codesandbox example.

When will they behave differently, apart from when dealing with DOM manipulation/event simulation?

Comment: because they are separate events technically. A click event captures the mouse click event. However, there are many ways a form could be submitted without click. From another JavaScript trigger, using a keyboard return, etc... so they are different.

Comment: If there are multiple buttons or inputs onsubmit submits the whole form by default and onclick can but is used for more dynamic things like slideouts and things, but it is really in the function you write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally, this is up to the browser. Some browsers might call a submit button's `onClick` when the form is submitted by pressing the return key, but the standard doesn't mandate this. Others might only call `onClick` when return is pressed *if the submit button is selected*. Others might not fire it unless the button is manually clicked.

If you want the best portability, use `onSubmit` for what it's designed for: to detect form submission.

Answer (score 3):

The other main difference is the target for the event.

```
Note that the submit event fires on the <form> element itself, and not on any <button> or <input type="submit"> inside it. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event